# Reading Excel with multiple header to Pandas DataFrame: dealing with "Unnamed" second header names

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have used `pd.read_excel("file", header=[0, 1])` to read an excel sheet where the two upper rows are header, and got the following structure:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Unnamed: 0_level_1 | Col B 1 |
| -------------------- | -------- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

How can I avoid the need to call `df["Column A"]["Unnamed: 0_level_1"]` to get the values of the first column, and simply use `df["Column A"]` ?

I tried `df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.match("Unnamed")]`, but it removed the whole column...

Comment: You must provide a reproducible example of the file's content. Can't you ignore the row during import?